# Intel SGX pass ints from Application to Enclave

Tags: c++, intel, sgx, enclave

I am trying to pass two integers to the SGX enclave, combine them and then return the result back to the application.
However, nothing seems to happen when compiling the code aside from the enclave getting created. No error given and it seemingly never reaches the ECALL function.

If anyone is aware of a tutorial that does this that I can use as reference then that would be hugely appreciated.

**EDL:**

```
enclave {
    from "sgx_tae_service.edl" import *;

    /* enum definition */
    enum TEE_ERROR {
        TEE_ERROR_INVALID_SIGNATURE = 0,
        TEE_ERROR_INVALID_COUNTER = 1,
        TEE_ERROR_INVALID_SECRET = 2
    };


    trusted {
        /* define ECALLs here. */
        public int in_enclave([in] int* a, [in] int* b);
};

    untrusted {
        /* define OCALLs here. */
        void ocall_print_int([out] int* i);
    };
};
```

**Enclave.cpp**

```
int in_enclave(int* a, int* b){
        ocall_print("In the Enclave.");
        int result =0;
        result = a + b;
        ocall_print_int(&result);

}
```

**App.cpp**

```
int test(void) {
    if (initialize_enclave(&global_eid, "enclave.token", "enclave.signed.so") < 0) {
        std::cout << "Fail to initialize enclave." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }else{

    std::cout<<"Enclave made. "<<"\n";
}
        int a =34, b =23,point = 0;
        in_enclave(global_eid,&point,&a,&b);

    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the corrections below. The trusted function `in_enclave` receives `a` and `b`, computes the sum, and returns the result. In the (untrusted) application code the function result is placed in `point`.

When calling the function check the return value. The return value, from the perspective of the main application code, is of type `sgx_status_t` where OK is `SGX_SUCCESS`. There is a list of error codes in the SGX developer reference or look for [`sgx_error.h`](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/blob/sgx_2.9.1/common/inc/sgx_error.h#L39) in the source code. In this example, we could use the value of `status` to find why the ecall failed.

### EDL

```
    trusted {
        public int in_enclave(int a, int b);
    };
```

### Enclave

```
    int in_enclave(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
```

### Application

```
    int a = 34, b = 23, point = 0;
    sgx_status_t status = in_enclave(global_eid, &point, a, b);
    if (SGX_SUCCESS != status) {
        // error occurred! 
    }
    printf("%d\n", point);
```